# javascript get a variable inside the express.js controller into mongoose schema's model pre save hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to get a variable which is inside express.js controller into the
 schema in order to perform some operation on the variable and result of
 the operation inside the schema. Example below

express.js

```
userschema.full_name = fullName;
userschema.other_fields = other_details;

var variableName = 'inside the controller';

schema2 = new schema(req.body);
schema1.save(function (err, result){
});
```

schema1.js

```
var schema1 = mongoose.Schema({
    full_name: String,
    other_fields : String//etc
})

schema1.pre('save', function(){
    var fullName = this.full_name;
    var otherFields = this.other_fields;

    //get variableName which is inside the controller
    //but is not a field in schema1

    //perform operation inside schema and compare 
    //result with controller variableName
})
```

How can I get variableName which is inside the controller but is not a 
field in schema1 perform operation inside schema and compare result 
with the controller variableName